# Static ARP entry on MC-LAG ICL Link in Juniper MX routers

Tags: juniper, juniper-mx

Can someone please explain in detail why we need to setup static arp entry on each MC-LAG peer. This is mentioned below in Juniper Documenttation

https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/mc-lag-feature-concepts.html

Its under topic **Virtual Router Redundancy Protocol (VRRP) over IRB and MAC Address Synchronization**

If you are using the VRRP over IRB method to enable Layer 3 functionality, you must configure static ARP entries for the IRB interface of the remote MC-LAG peer to allow routing protocols to run over the IRB interfaces. `This step is required so you can issue the ping command to reach both the physical IP addresses and virtual IP addresses of the MC-LAG peers.`

But why this thing wont work without using static ARP? Can someone please explain this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't even tell you how much this requirement frustrated me as well, thank you for asking this one.

> Can someone please explain in detail why we need to setup static arp entry on each MC-LAG peer.

The static ARP/ND entries are required because *dynamic* ARP/ND learning is disabled on the ICL (this is not something you can enable via config).

The good news is that anything running Junos 15.1R3/16.1R1 or higher no longer has this restriction.  The documentation is simply out of date, unfortunately.